# Dynamic Table With Add Row And Ajax Post

Tags: javascript, html, pdo

I have an stock listing html table. Adding rows or deleting rows with this javascript.

```
 <script>
function addRow(dataTable) {
"use strict";
var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
if(rowCount < 20){
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;}  
}else{
     alert("En fazla 20 satır ekleyebilirsiniz.");
           
}
}

function deleteRow(dataTable) {
"use strict";
var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
    if(null !== chkbox && true === chkbox.checked) {
        if(rowCount <= 1) {
            alert("Tüm satırları silemezsiniz.");
            break;
        }
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
    }
}
    }
  </script>
```

And in each row i have select option which retrieves data from mysql database including stock ids.
When i select a stock from select option, getting price of from mysql table and showing in third td with ajax post.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tek_ice_stok_id").on('change',function(){
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var tek_ice_stok_id = row.find(".tek_ice_stok_id").val();
    var tek_ice_birim_fiyat = row.find(".tek_ice_birim_fiyat").val();
    var dataString = "tek_ice_stok_id="+tek_ice_stok_id; 

  $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "stok_fiyat_cek.php", 
    data: dataString, 
    success: function(result){ 
      row.find("td:eq(3)").html(result);
      
    }
  });
});
  })();
</script>
```

My first problem is when i add rows, the prices are all same in each rows price area. So i should do something and when i select 2nd or 3rd,etc select optons ajax should bring me those stocks prices.

Can anyone help me about this?

Thanks.

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRkWB.jpg)

Searched for it many times but couldnt find exactly same.

Comment: _newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;_ This line will just copy first row cells content into the newly created row. So it is expected that you have same content in each row when you add new one.

Comment: But when i fill first row inputs or select option and then add row, other rows are appearing empty. Not copying first row. I dont want it to copy of course but when it bring only ajax result to the second or 3rd rows?

Comment: Share and image of how the table looks like so that it comes out clear on what your trying to solve

Comment: I added image. In 1st row stock choosen, 2nd not choosen, 3rd chosen. But all prices are coming same as first row.